# special case of serializing form to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

building upon the `$.fn.serializeObject()` function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery/1186309#1186309), i'd like to be able to support "dot notation" in my form names, like so:

```
<form>
    <input name="Property.Items[0].Text" value="item 1" />
    <input name="Property.Items[0].Value" value="1" />
    <input name="Property.Items[1].Text" value="item 2" />
    <input name="Property.Items[1].Value" value="2" />
</form>
```

given that `$('form').serializeArray()` produces the following:

```
[{"name":"Property.Items[0].Text","value":"item 1"},
 {"name":"Property.Items[0].Value","value":"1"},
 {"name":"Property.Items[1].Text","value":"item 2"},
 {"name":"Property.Items[1].Value","value":"2"}]
```

how could i achieve the desired result below:

```
{Property: {Items: [{Text: 'item 1', Value: '1'},
                    {Text: 'item 2', Value: '2'}]} }
```

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
to be specific, the desired code would be added to the `serializeObject` extension so that in addition to the way it works now, it would also support the above convention.  here's the existing method for convenience.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

EDIT 2:
feeding off the answer provided, here's my current implementation:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  var o = {};
  var a = this.serializeArray();
  var regArray = /^([^\[\]]+)\[(\d+)\]$/;

  $.each(a, function(i) {
      var name = this.name;
      var value = this.value;

      // let's also allow for "dot notation" in the input names
      var props = name.split('.');
      var position = o;
      while (props.length) {
          var key = props.shift();
          var matches;
          if (matches = regArray.exec(key)) {
              var p = matches[1];
              var n = matches[2];
              if (!position[p]) position[p] = [];
              if (!position[p][n]) position[p][n] = {};
              position = position[p][n];
          } else {
              if (!props.length) {
                  if (!position[key]) position[key] = value || '';
                  else if (position[key]) {
                      if (!position[key].push) position[key] = [position[key]];
                      position[key].push(value || '');
                  }
              } else {
                  if (!position[key]) position[key] = {};
                  position = position[key];
              }
          }
      }
  });
  return o;
};
```

you can see it in action [here](http://jsbin.com/ewono4/edit)

Comment: Nice, 2 things. There's no need to use $.each here it's just overhead. A regular for-loop will do it. 2. Don't declare `var` in a loop (for, while). In Javascript re-assigning a var is way faster then declare a new `var` each time. So set you `var` outside the loops.

Comment: @Omer, what does your /^([^\[\]]+)\[(\d+)\]$/ expression check exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is a bit static. But it should do the trick:

```
var serialized = $.fn.serializeObject(),
            properties = {},
            property = [],
            position = {},
            key = '',
            n = 0,
            matchName = '',
            i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < serialized.length; i += 1) {
            property = serialized[i].name.split('.');
            position = properties;
            while (property.length) {
                key = property.shift();
                if (key.match(/\[\d+\]/) && key.match(/\[\d+\]/).join().match(/\d+/g) ) {
                    matchName = key.match(/\w+/)[0]
                    n = parseInt(key.match(/\[\d+\]/).join().match(/\d+/g), 10);
                    if (!position[matchName]) {
                        position[matchName] = [];
                    }

                    if (!position[matchName][n]) {
                        position[matchName][n] = {}
                    }

                    position = position[matchName][n]
                } else {
                    if (!property.length) {
                        position[key] = serialized[i].value
                    } else {
                        if (!position[key]) {
                            position[key] = {};
                        }
                        position = position[key]
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        console.log(properties);
```

Comment: +1 thanks.  it does seem to work after changing $.fn.serializeObject() to $().serializeArray().  will test in more detail and follow up.

Comment: i was able to improve upon your answer... check it out in the post.  thanks again.